# Rails 3: calling database on a has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

Hi I have a many to many association where 'posts' have many 'feeling', I'd like to figure out how to find all the posts with a specific feeling by the user. My Feeling model has a 'name' attribute.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts, :dependent => :destroy
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :feelingships
  has_many :feelings, :through => :feelingships
  belongs_to :user
end

class Feeling < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :feelingships
  has_many :posts, :through => :feelingships
end


class Feelingship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :feeling
  attr_accessible :post_id, :feeling_id
end
```

I tried this but it says I have the wrong association: "ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError: Association named 'feeling' was not found; perhaps you misspelled it?"

```
 def feeling
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @feed_items= @user.posts.includes(:feeling).where(
          ['`feelings`.name = ?', params[:feeling]])
  @feed_items = @feed_items.paginate(:per_page => "10", :page => params[:page])
render 'shared/_feed', :layout => 'head_layout'
end
```

Comment: What is "feed" that you're calling on @user ? It should probably be "posts" instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `includes` argument should be `:feelings` - notice the plural, which is what your association is named.

So it should be:

```
@user.posts.includes(:feelings)
```